# React route declare syntax

Tags: react-router

I am trying to use React-Route. I declared the routes as below:

```
var routes = (
        <Route path="/" component={App}>
            <IndexRoute component={HomePage}></IndexRoute>
            <Route path="courses" component={CoursesPage}></Route>
            <Route path="course" component={ManageCoursePage}></Route>
            <Route path="course/:id" component={ManageCoursePage}></Route>
            <Route path="about" component={AboutPage} />
        </Route>
    );
```

export default routes;

I am wondering if it is JS syntax or React JSX syntax ...

I want to generate this Route dynamically from JSON data for example ...

Thanks,

Comment: That is JSX syntax. Not sure what your specific question is.

Comment: Hi, I want to generate the Route dynamically. Maybe from database I have a menu table ...... Any idea how to do it? Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

If its a component then you can dynamically add it. Eg.

```
componentData = [{ name: 'one' : component : Component (import Component from './somewhere') type: IndexRoute/Route, path: '/somewhere' }]
```

and then you use it

```
componentData.map(Comp => (<Comp.type path={Comp.path} component={Comp.component})
```

you can figure out the rest for nesting.

Comment: Thanks, I will try.